# Intergration of Paypal

Tags: mysql, paypal, authentication, phpmyadmin, discounts

i am thinking of integrating paypal into my clients website however wanted to check about a few things that i couldn't find in the documentation. I already have a working login system that starts a session upon logging in however my client wants the ability to give certain customers discounts. The discount amount can be manually added to the SQL database used for login (kept on PHPmyadmin) however is there any way for at checkout Paypal to take this value and subtract that percent form the total amount to be paid?

Many Thanks

Tom

Comment: My understanding is that you pass the amount to Paypal.  Any discounting would be done before you communicate to Paypal.

Comment: How and when do i do this though? is it upon selecting the item i tell the script to subtract the percent from it or is it later?